# ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[16,224,224,256] and type bool

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, deep-learning

I am very new to deep learning. I am implementing CNN+VGG 16 model for image colorization. But I have used too many layers in the model. This model showed an error
when I used 300 batch size. Guide me to which layers I can remove?
Model is taking too much time for fit.

```
# Importing Libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Input, InputLayer, Conv2D,UpSampling2D,DepthwiseConv2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose, Reshape, Flatten,LeakyReLU, Dropout,DepthwiseConv2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten,MaxPooling2D,Conv2DTranspose, AveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16  import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model,Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from PIL import Image
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
import cv2

#load data
ab = np.load('ab1.npy')
gray = np.load('gray_scale.npy')
ab.shape #(10000, 224, 224, 2)

def get_rbg(gray_imgs, ab_imgs, n = 10):
    
    #create an empty array to store images
    img1 = np.zeros((n, 224, 224, 3))
    
    img1[:, :, :, 0] = gray_imgs[0:n:]
    img1[:, :, :, 1:] = ab_imgs[0:n:]
    
    #convert all the images to type unit8
    img1 = img1.astype("uint8")
    
    #create a new empty array
    imgs= []
    
    for i in range(0, n):
        imgs.append(cv2.cvtColor(img1[i], cv2.COLOR_LAB2RGB))
        
    #convert the image matrix into a numpy array
    imgs = np.array(imgs)
    
    return imgs
img_out = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input(get_rbg(gray_imgs = gray, ab_imgs = ab, n = 100))# 300

img_out.shape #(100, 224, 224, 3)
```

model defination:

```
model6 = VGG16(weights='imagenet',include_top=False,input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(img_in.shape[1], img_in.shape[2], 3)))
model.add(Model(inputs=model6.inputs, outputs=model6.layers[-10].output))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(DepthwiseConv2D(32, (2, 2), activation=tf.nn.relu, padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(DepthwiseConv2D(32, (2, 2), activation=tf.nn.relu, padding='same'))
model.add(layers.ReLU(0.3))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.4))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(DepthwiseConv2D(2, (2, 2), activation=tf.nn.relu, padding='same'))
model.add(layers.ReLU(0.3))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.ReLU(0.3))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Dense(units=3))
print(model.summary())

Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
functional_1 (Functional)    (None, 56, 56, 256)       1735488   
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d (UpSampling2D) (None, 112, 112, 256)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_1 (UpSampling2 (None, 224, 224, 256)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
depthwise_conv2d (DepthwiseC (None, 112, 112, 256)     262400    
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_2 (UpSampling2 (None, 224, 224, 256)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
depthwise_conv2d_1 (Depthwis (None, 112, 112, 256)     262400    
_________________________________________________________________
re_lu (ReLU)                 (None, 112, 112, 256)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 112, 112, 256)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_3 (UpSampling2 (None, 224, 224, 256)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_4 (UpSampling2 (None, 448, 448, 256)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
depthwise_conv2d_2 (Depthwis (None, 224, 224, 256)     1280      
_________________________________________________________________
re_lu_1 (ReLU)               (None, 224, 224, 256)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 224, 224, 256)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_5 (UpSampling2 (None, 448, 448, 256)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
re_lu_2 (ReLU)               (None, 448, 448, 256)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 448, 448, 256)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
average_pooling2d (AveragePo (None, 224, 224, 256)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 224, 224, 3)       771       
=================================================================
Total params: 2,262,339
Trainable params: 2,262,339
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
model.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),loss = 'mse',metrics=tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy())
#if you encounter an OOM error, reduce the batch_size to 8
model.fit(img_in, img_out, epochs =5, batch_size = 5)
```

please tell me which layers can I drop from model. so that my model can run with less time and it will consume less resource.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce your batch size - removing layers would detriment performance. A quick search shows that VGG16 consumes about 200mb for backpropogation, meaning at batch size 300, you would need about 60gb of RAM or vRAM.

Reference:
https://forums.fast.ai/t/vgg16-memory-vs-parameter-in-3d-model/18117